# magento 1.9 export all products not work

Tags: export

i try to export all products by using magento default "Export All Products" data profile, but it not works, when i click "Run Profile in Popup" it just loads a while and then displays

```
 Starting profile execution, please wait...
 Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data
```

there is no export_all_products.csv in my var/export folder, any ideas?

Comment: raise the memory_limit and the max_execution_time.

Comment: The same problem.
Memory limit set up as: php_value memory_limit 256M php_value max_execution_time 18000 The same settings on second store with the same size of database working well. Sorry I'm new here, but when I try add a comment I receive message "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt : Does solve your problem